# Разрешить все всплывающие окна в Safari на iOS для определённого сайта

Tags: ipad, всплывающее-окно, ios, вёрстка, safari

Здравствуйте.
Есть ли возможность разрешить все всплывающие окна на iOS 6.1 (конкретно на iPad) для определённого сайта? Сейчас ситуация такая: есть веб-приложение с большим количеством попапов. В настройках блокировка попапов отключена. При клике по кнопке, которая вызывает попап, появляется запрос от системы "Запретить/Разрешить", если разрешаем, то далее этот попап будет открываться без запроса, а для каждого нового окна с другими URL всё равно появляется этот запрос. Можно это как-то обойти через настройки Safari или какие-то метатеги? 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, что нельзя их обойти. Единственным выходом оказалось избавиться от "отложенных" попапов. Запрос на разрешение открытия попапа выдаётся, если попап появляется не в результате прямого действия пользователя (то есть нажали кнопку, она вызвала window.open другого окна), например, если его вызов завернуть в setTimeout. Поэтому нужно сделать вызов попапа синхронным, а от асинхронных вызовов избавиться, получив и кэшировав все необходимые данные.